# Qooxdoo POST got error 414 Request-URI Too Large

Tags: qooxdoo

I am creating application with qooxdoo and using qx.io.remote.Request class to request to apache server. I already set the method to POST using setMethod('POST'). When I created long request I got error **414 Request-URI Too Large**,

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you may use 2 way:

1. Server side: You need to resetting your Apache Tomcat setting to allow more than 8KB at maxHttpHeaderSize tag. you may do this at CAROLINA_HOME/conf/server.xml
2. Fix your apps whithout showing your parameter in URL. But sorry, i have same problem for this point. i still not success to do this.